# ISC DHCP Different DNS Server For Different Client OS

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp, router

Is it possible to configure `isc-dhcp` in a way that it can send different DNS server addresses to different clients in the network?

Let say I have some Macs, PCs with Linux and Windows in the network. My primary DNS server is `bind9` under Linux, but I have also a Windows server how also act as a DNS. Now I want that `isc-dhcp` send to the Windows clients the DNS connection to the Windows server and all other computer in the network get the DNS settings from the dhcp/bind9.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can provide different settings based on the client. This is done by filtering on `vendor-class-identifier`. See this mailing list discussion: https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2010-May/011783.html

Comment: @muru: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby it's basically a link-only answer, and I don't know enough to write a decent answer. You can post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer I get from muru, I found this workaround out:

For find out the `vender-class-identifier` from the clients, you need to put this on top from the `dhcpd.conf`:

```
set vendor-string = option vendor-class-identifier;
```

After restarting the dhcp service and a new connection to the dhcp server from a client you can use `cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` to see which is your class. For example Windows XP has: `"MSFT 5.0"`

Now you can clarify the DNS Servers for the Clients like this, inside a subnet block:

```
# DNS for Windows XP
if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "MSFT 5.0"
{
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;
}
# DNS for all others
else
{
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.254, 8.8.8.8;
}
```

I am not sure that we need the `0, 9` variable, maybe not.